# Android - contact picker in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contacts, contacts, contactpicker

I have a viewpager/sliding tabs. I want to be able to get 4 contacts from the address book that is already on the phone and save them in the app for later use. I have the code to do contact picker with an activity but my contact page is a fragment and I have yet to get it to work.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Code for the Main activity it is connected to:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);


    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Contacts").setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("GPS").setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Message").setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

}


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new MainMenu_Contacts();
            case 1:
                return new MainMenu_GPS();
            case 2:
                return new MainMenu_Message();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}

//implements on pager selected
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

}


//implements tab listener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
}
```

XML for main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code for contact fragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainMenu_Contacts extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

private Button mBtnContacts;
private final int PICK = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu__contacts);
    mBtnContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xBtnContacts);
    mBtnContacts.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Opening Contacts Window as a Window
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    // calling OnActivityResult with intenet And Some conatct for Identifie
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null,     null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.People.NAME));
                    // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected     contact
                    // name.
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

XML for contact:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/xBtnContacts"
    android:text="Pick Contacts" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you need further help, please provide the code for the contact stuff

Answer (score 0):

The contacts from phone are read via a `ContentProvider` that needs the permissions in your app. Maybe this is your problem since you didn't mention them.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used contact picker with the following steps. You can change `ImageButton` with your view class

```
ImageButton pick_contact = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pick_contact);
pick_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
});
```

Later in activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (data != null) {
        Uri result = data.getData();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?",
                new String[]{result.getLastPathSegment()}, null);

        if (c.getCount() >= 1 && c.moveToFirst()) {

            final String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    }
}
```

Important: In AndroidManifest.xml, add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**UPDATE:**
Take a look at: https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker